# Can not install angularjs in .net core Visual Studio 2015

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-1.0

i am trying to install angularjs in asp.net core but it is shows dependencies(Restroing...)

[image]

Comment: Do u see any errors in output window?

Answer (score 0):

try this

[AngularJS and ASP.net Core 1.0](http://www.fiyazhasan.me/angularjs-and-asp-net-core-1-0-jumpstart-part-iii/)